# KeyError: 6 when adding labels to a regplot

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataframe with the following columns: 'Project', 'Hours', 'Revenue', 'Rate'

I try to build a regplot with Rate on X-axis and Revenue on the Y-axis and add Project name label to the dots at my regplot. Here is my code:

```
ax=sns.regplot(x = 'Revenue', y = 'Rate',data= df_hours_revenue, ci = None)
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(20,10)})
# ax.set_xlabel('')
# ax.set_ylabel('Rate (£/hour)')
sns.set_context('poster')
plt.title("Rate vs. project revenue 2018-2019")

for line in range(0,df_hours_revenue.shape[0]):
     ax.text(df_hours_revenue.Revenue[line], df_hours_revenue.Rate[line], 
     df_hours_revenue.Project[line], horizontalalignment='left', 
     size='small', color='Black', weight='normal')
```

The result is a graph with **some** labels added and this output error which I do not understand:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-fdcfd6157523> in <module>
      9 
     10 for line in range(0,df_hours_revenue.shape[0]):
---> 11      ax.text(df_hours_revenue.Revenue[line], df_hours_revenue.Rate[line], 
     12      df_hours_revenue.Project[line], horizontalalignment='left',
     13      size='small', color='Black', weight='normal')

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    866         key = com.apply_if_callable(key, self)
    867         try:
--> 868             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
    869 
    870             if not is_scalar(result):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   4373         try:
   4374             return self._engine.get_value(s, k,
-> 4375                                           tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
   4376         except KeyError as e1:
   4377             if len(self) > 0 and (self.holds_integer() or self.is_boolean()):

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 6
```

Comment: Unless you share some part of your dataframe, it is hard to guess what is going wrong. Since you seem to be new to Stack Overflow, you should read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access Series' item by its position, you should be using `.iloc`, e.g.:

```
df_hours_revenue.Revenue.iloc[line]
```

Read more [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html).